# ExtJS conditionally render input fields

Tags: javascript, extjs, filtering

I have the following code in ExtJS

```
var formPanel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
title: 'Panel title',
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
items: [{
    xtype: 'container',
    layout: 'hbox',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'First Name', 
        name: 'FirstName',
    }, {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Last Name',  
        name: 'LastName',
    },{
        xtype:'fieldset',
        title: 'Phone Number',
        defaultType: 'textfield',
        items :[{
                fieldLabel: 'Home',
                name: 'home',
                value: '(888) 555-1212'
            },{
                fieldLabel: 'Business',
                name: 'business',
                toBeRendered: IS_BUSINESS_FIELD_SUPPORTED_IN_CURRENT_RELEASE // custom property that must restrict rendering
                rendered: IS_BUSINESS_FIELD_SUPPORTED_IN_CURRENT_RELEASE //doesn't work
            }]
    }]
}]
});
```

I want to create an application, that will have properties file where I can set up flags for `SUPPORTED` fields e.g `IS_BUSINESS_FIELD_SUPPORTED_IN_CURRENT_RELEASE = false`. If it's false than text input  `fieldLabel: 'Business'` will not be rendered at all - no hidden/disabled text input `Business` in html.

I've tried `rendered` property - but it doesn't work, the only solution so far is to use `items = Ext.Array.filter(items,filterFunction)` in `onRender`;

Are there any other solutions how can I restrict rendering input elements?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just build the dynamic items before rendering it? It's just an array.

Comment: I think that best approach is to define custom components for your application parts and add required components within its `constructor`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the constructor, use the `initItems` method:

```
Ext.define('MyComponent', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    xtype: 'mycomponent',

    bodyPadding: 10,
    border: true,
    title: 'My component',

    items : [
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'My allowed button'
        }
    ],

    initItems : function() {
        var items = this.items;

        // Your conditions
        if (false) {
            items.push({
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'My denied button'
            });
        }

        this.callParent();
    }
});
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/17qi

Answer (score 1):

I think that best approach is to define custom components for your application parts and add required components within its `constructor`, like this:

```
constructor: function () {
    var myComponentItems = [
    {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'My allowed button'
        }
    ];

    // Your conditions
    if(false) {
        myComponentItems.push({
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'My denied button'
        });
    }

    Ext.apply(this, {
        items: myComponentItems
    });

    this.callParent(arguments);
}
```

[Working fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/17pp)